# How save file with utf-16-le bom encoding?

Tags: python, utf-16, byte-order-mark, utf-16le

I can save file to `utf-16-le`, but i dont understand how save with `bom` it.

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', mode='a', newline='', encoding='utf-16-le') as employee_file:
    writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=";")
    row = ['Job1', 'M']
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I can add `'\ufeff` to start of file, but i search alternative variant

Comment: Why do you need to add a BOM? If the encoding of the file is declared to be `utf-16-le`, then there should be no BOM. See https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom9 ("if a text data stream is marked as UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE or UTF-32LE, a BOM is neither necessary nor permitted").

Comment: You may use just `utf-16`, which will put the BOM (but no guarantee that it is LE). On your case, it is also more tricky: you have mode `a`, and in theory code should ignore if the file it is at beginning or in the middle (where BOM) are not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

```
def addUTF8Bom(filename):
  f = codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-16-le')
  content = f.read()
  f.close()
  f2 = codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'utf-16-le')
  f2.write(u'\ufeff')
  f2.write(content)
  f2.close()
```

Comment: 1) Please don't post an answer with only code and no explanatory text. 2) What are your reasons for breaking the guidelines from the Unicode consortium (see link in comment on the question)? 3) The OP already said "I can add `'\ufeff` to start of file".